# 3rd Party Library causes Webpack to throw "Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression" warning

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack, vscode-extensions

I have been working on vscode extension and I tried bundling it using Webpack. My project uses another project, that has been linked in node_modules. I can't activate extension using bundled js file. 3rd party library in nested project uses sync-rpc, which has dynamic require call in it. It causes:

```
WARNING in ../twx-service-helper/node_modules/sync-rpc/lib/worker.js 52:10-27
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

I tried using nodeExternals to externailze node_modules, tried externalizing sync-rpc in Webpack.config.js, removing request calls in nested project, updating sync-rpc, deleting package-lock.json file and executing npm install, but nothing works. My Webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    target: "node",
    mode: "production",
    entry: "./src/extension.ts",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "out"),
    },
    devtool: "none",
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: "ts-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".js"],
    },
    externals: {
        vscode: "commonjs vscode",
    },
};
```

Comment: I have a similar problem and all I could find so far is: ignore the warning. It means that there's somewhere an import (require) with an expression (e.g. lib name in a variable), so webpackage cannot determine which module is loaded there. IMO this warning should be suppressable as you often can't do anything about it (particularly when this comes from a 3rd party module).

Comment: Yes, you can suppress this warning by adding in webpack.config.js module:

`exprContextCritical: false`

But when i try to run extension with this warning, it doesn't work correctly, it doesn't even activate. VS code messes up paths and all i get is this error:

`Error: Cannot find module\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\53`

There is no such file as 53 in vs code folder and don't implicitly create one. Also, if i don't use webpack and let Typescript build transcompile project, everything works fine.